# how to place passport js configuration in a common file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using [Passport js](http://passportjs.org/) for authentication in my project. At server side i am using [Express js](http://expressjs.com/). In `app.js` i have configuration for passport js and the code is:

```
passport.use(new Strategy({
  passReqToCallback: true
},
  function (req, username, password, done) {
    req.models.users.find({ 'user_id' : username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user[0]) {
        console.log("The username is Incorrect");
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (user[0].default_password!=password) {
        console.log("The Password is Incorrect");
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});
```

and after this i am verifying the client request like this:

```
  app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Till here everything is working fine.
**Now** i want to place this route `app.post('/login',...` in routes folder so i have given the path of the route in `app.js` like this:

```
var users = require('./routes/users/users');
app.use('/users', users);
```

**My problem is:** in this user route file i don't have passport configuration and i don't want to rewrite it again for all my other routes so i am thinking to place the passport configuration in a common file and reuse it but i don't know how to do it. If you have any idea please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a middleware, lets call it `auth.js`, that checks for session info and mount this for every route that you need.

```
'use strict';

const qs   = require('querystring'),
    router = require('express').Router();

router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // set this in res.locals
    if (!req.user) {
        return res.redirect('/?' + qs.stringify({
            'r': req.originalUrl
        }));
    }

    next();
});

module.exports = router;
```

If you use the above approach, you will need to add `res.locals.user = req.user;` in your `server/app.js`.

After this, you can require the above middleware on every route that needs to be authenticated.

```
router.verb('/path', require('./path-to-auth'));
router.verb('/path', (req, res, next) => {
 // this route will only be executed if the user is authenticated
});
```

Comment: thanks, can you tell me what is the significance of `// set this in res.locals
    if (!req.user) {
        return res.redirect('/?' + qs.stringify({
            'r': req.originalUrl
        }));
    }` i mean what it will do?

Comment: Should i write passport configuration in `auth.js` or it can be placed in `app.js` ?

Comment: Its just a way of redirecting the user to the desired page after login. Passport stuff can be in a `login.js` file that you mount after your routes

Comment: Ok i got your point! Now tell me in  `app.js` where should i place `res.locals.user = req.user;`?

Comment: After `app.use(passport.initialize()); app.use(passport.session());` put it in a middleware `app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.user    = req.user;
    next();
});`